# Input function for technical / biological replicates in snakemake

Tags: snakemake

I´m currently trying to write a Snakemake workflow that can check automatically via a sample.tsv file if a given sample is a biological or technical replicate. And then use in this case at some point of my workflow a rule to merge technical/biological replicates.

My tsv file looks like this:

```
|sample    | unit_bio | unit_tech | fq1 | fq2 |                                                                                                                      
|----------|----------|-----------|-----|-----|
| bCalAnn1 |        1 |         1 | /home/assembly_downstream/data/arima_HiC/bCalAnn1_1_1_R1.fastq.gz | /home/assembly_downstream/data/arima_HiC/bCalAnn1_1_1_R2.fastq.gz |
| bCalAnn1 |        1 |         2 | /home/assembly_downstream/data/arima_HiC/bCalAnn1_1_2_R1.fastq.gz | /home/assembly_downstream/data/arima_HiC/bCalAnn1_1_2_R2.fastq.gz |
| bCalAnn2 |        1 |         1 | /home/assembly_downstream/data/arima_HiC/bCalAnn2_1_1_R1.fastq.gz | /home/assembly_downstream/data/arima_HiC/bCalAnn2_1_1_R2.fastq.gz |
| bCalAnn2 |        1 |         2 | /home/assembly_downstream/data/arima_HiC/bCalAnn2_1_2_R1.fastq.gz | /home/assembly_downstream/data/arima_HiC/bCalAnn2_1_2_R2.fastq.gz |
| bCalAnn2 |        2 |         1 | /home/assembly_downstream/data/arima_HiC/bCalAnn2_2_1_R1.fastq.gz | /home/assembly_downstream/data/arima_HiC/bCalAnn2_2_1_R2.fastq.gz |
| bCalAnn2 |        3 |         1 | /home/assembly_downstream/data/arima_HiC/bCalAnn2_3_1_R1.fastq.gz | /home/assembly_downstream/data/arima_HiC/bCalAnn2_3_1_R2.fastq.gz |
```

My Pipeline looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import yaml

configfile: "config.yaml"


samples = pd.read_table(config["samples"], dtype=str)

rule all:
    input:
        expand(config["arima_mapping"] + "final/{sample}_{unit_bio}_{unit_tech}.bam", zip, 
            sample=samples["sample"], unit_bio=samples["unit_bio"], unit_tech=samples["unit_tech"])



..
some rules
..

rule add_read_groups:
    input:
        config["arima_mapping"] + "paired/{sample}_{unit_bio}_{unit_tech}.bam"
    output:
        config["arima_mapping"] + "paired_read_groups/{sample}_{unit_bio}_{unit_tech}.bam"
    params:
        platform = "ILLUMINA",
        sampleName = "{sample}",
        library = "{sample}",
        platform_unit ="None"
    conda:
        "../envs/arima_mapping.yaml"
    log:
        config["logs"] + "arima_mapping/paired_read_groups/{sample}_{unit_bio}_{unit_tech}.log"
    shell:
        "picard AddOrReplaceReadGroups I={input} O={output} SM={params.sampleName} LB={params.library} PU={params.platform_unit} PL={params.platform} 2> {log}"

rule merge_tech_repl:
    input:
        config["arima_mapping"] + "paired_read_groups/{sample}_{unit_bio}_{unit_tech}.bam" 
    output:
        config["arima_mapping"] + "merge_tech_repl/{sample}_{unit_bio}_{unit_tech}.bam"
    params:
        val_string = "SILENT" 
    conda:
        "../envs/arima_mapping.yaml"
    log:
        config["logs"] + "arima_mapping/merged_tech_repl/{sample}_{unit_bio}_{unit_tech}.log"
    threads:
        2 #verwendet nur maximal 2
    shell:
        "picard MergeSamFiles -I {input} -O {output} --ASSUME_SORTED true --USE_THREADING true --VALIDATION_STRINGENCY {params.val_string} 2> {log}"


rule mark_duplicates:
    input:
        config["arima_mapping"] + "merge_tech_repl/{sample}_{unit_bio}_{unit_tech}.bam" if config["tech_repl"] else config["arima_mapping"] + "paired_read_groups/{sample}_{unit_bio}_{unit_tech}.bam"
    output:
        bam = config["arima_mapping"] + "final/{sample}_{unit_bio}_{unit_tech}.bam",
        metric = config["arima_mapping"] + "final/metric_{sample}_{unit_bio}_{unit_tech}.txt"
    #params:
    conda:
        "../envs/arima_mapping.yaml"
    log:
        config["logs"] + "arima_mapping/mark_duplicates/{sample}_{unit_bio}_{unit_tech}.log"
    shell:
        "picard MarkDuplicates I={input} O={output.bam} M={output.metric} 2> {log}"
```

At the moment I have set a boolean in a config file that tells the `mark_duplicates` rule whether to take its input from the `add_read_group` or the `merge_technical_replicates` rule.  This is of course not optimal since it could be that some samples may have duplicates (of any numbers) while others don´t. Therefore I want to create a syntax that checks the tsv table if a given sample name and unit_bio number are identical while the unit_tech number is different (and later analog to this for biological replicates), thus merging these specific samples while nonduplicate samples skip the merging rule.

**EDIT**

For clarification since I think I explained my goal confusingly.
My first attempt looks like this, I want "i" to be flexible, in case the duplicate number changes. I don't think that my input function returns all duplicates together that match each other but gives them one by one which is not what I want. I´m also unsure on how I would have to handle samples that do not have duplicates since they would have to skip this rule somehow.

```
  input_function(wildcards):
        return expand({sample}_{unit_bio}_{i}.bam", sample = wildcards.sample,
                                                    unit_bio = wildcards.unit_bio,
                                                    i = samples["sample"].str.count(wildcards.sample))

rule tech_duplicate_check:
    input:
        input_function #(that returns a list of 2-n duplicates, where n could be different for each sample)
    output:
        {sample}_{unit_bio}.bam
    shell:
        MergeTechDupl_tool {input} # input is a list
```

Comment: Can you clarify this: Your final output is `final/{sample}_{unit_bio}_{unit_tech}.bam`. However, if you merge technical replicates you should end up with something like `final/{sample}_{unit_bio}.bam` and if merge technical and biologcal replicates you would have `final/{sample}.bam`. I mean, if you merge `rep1` and `rep2` the output is just "rep" you wouldn't call it either rep1 or rep2 anymore. Am I missing something?

Comment: My bad, you are correct. I didn´t do this on purpose.

Answer (score 0):

> Therefore I want to create a syntax that checks the tsv table if a given sample name and unit_bio number are identical while the unit_tech number is different (and later analog to this for biological replicates), thus merging these specific samples while nonduplicate samples skip the merging rule.

```
rule gather_techdups_of_a_biodup:
    output: "{sample}/{unit_bio}"
    input: gather_techdups_of_a_biodup_input_fn
    shell: "true"  # Fill this in

rule gather_biodips_of_a_techdup:
    output: "{sample}/{unit_tech}"
    input: gather_biodips_of_a_techdup_input_fn
    shell: "true"  # Fill this in
```

> After some attempts my main problem I struggle with is the table checking. As far as I know snakemake takes templates as input and checks for all samples that match this. But I would need to check the table for every sample that shares (e.g. for technical replicate) the sample name and the unit_bio number take all these samples and give them as input for the first rule run. Then I would have to take the next sample which was not already part of a previous run to prevent merging the same samples multiple times.

The logic you describe here can be implemented in the `gather_techdups_of_a_biodup_input_fn` and `gather_biodips_of_a_techdup_input_fn` functions above. For example, read your sample TSV file with pandas, filter for `wildcards.sample` and `wildcards.unit_bio` (or `wildcards.unit_tech`), then extract columns `fq1` and `fq2` from the filtered data frame.

Comment: That does not answer my question, I know that the blueprint for the input functions would look like this, my problem is that I don´t know if there is a snakemake syntax to extract an unknown number of duplicate pairs (could be 2, could be 3, etc.) based on values in a tsv table. As I would have to use the rule on all duplicates of a pair at the same time.

Comment: @snakelake There is no built-in syntax to interact with tabular data, as far as I know. The logic in handling the tabular data must then be implemented in something like pandas, within the input function.